# How long will Ubuntu 13.04 be supported for?

Tags: release-management

I am trying to find out how long will Ubuntu 13.04 be supported before the next version arrives.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The ubuntu wiki has a graph for this (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS for more information).

[image]

Ubuntu also has a 6 months cycle where new releases are release on the 4th and 10th month of the year (hence the 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, 13.10 etc).

> A new LTS version is released every 2 years. In previous releases, a Long Term Support (LTS) version had 3 years support on Ubuntu (Desktop) and 5 years on Ubuntu Server. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, both versions will receive 5 years support. There is no extra fee for the LTS version; we make our very best work available to everyone on the same free terms. Upgrades to new versions of Ubuntu are and always will be free of charge.

Comment: Can't get a better answer than that image ^^.

Answer (score 4):

According to [wiki Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), 13.04 will be supported until: 2014.10 (October)

That's the official support. But Ubuntu get's a new version every 6 months. So next one after 13.04, is in October 2013, called 13.10

Comment: This version is only supported for a year? I might wait for 13.10 for release next year. Why only a year?

Comment: 18 months, not a year.

Comment: This is not actually correct.  Support for 13.04 ends in January 2014.  Canonical decided to shorten the usual 18-month support period for recent non-LTS releases down to 9 months.

Answer (score 0):

13.04 is only supported until January 2014? That's unfortunate. I was hoping to skip 13.10.

Since, from 13.10, it is no longer possible to move an installation to new hardware (motherboard), I have to stick to 13.04. There are also some other annoyances in 13.10 (e.g., Nautilus).

But,if no support anymore, I may have to install 12.04. which means a major effort.