# Is the update 13.10 good?

Tags: updates

I just got a update notification saying version 13.10 of ubuntu can be updated. I wanted to see if anyone has updated and if so, is it good and is there any bugs in it?

**~Steam gamer**

Comment: `is it good`. You should be more specific

Comment: This question is down to personal opinion and so can not get a simple answer.  If you want to gauge popular opinion you are probably better asking this on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded. Really like it so far. It doesn't have any big new features, but it does some awesome under the hood improvements. Especially on the gaming side and looking at your name, you might be interested in that! There have been a lot of performance improvements for 3D applications (like games).

Other notable new features are:

- **Smart Scopes:** You can now search for a lot of other sources than just Amazon. Also you can turn of the scopes you aren't intested in.
- **Updated packages:** All standard applications like LibreOffice, Firefox and Thunderbird are updated to the latest version

Comment: For me the upgrade broke a bunch of things. Initially it wouldn't even start lightdm. Broke udev rules, broke my keyboard layout, my printing. Kinda horrid really. I fixed all that by now, but I was really pissed.

Comment: I did a clean install (I used the same Ubuntu installation for the past 2 years, with just upgrading from release to release :P) it never broke for me really. But if it goes horribly wrong as in this case.. a clean install is just the best option. Also this is why you should always make proper backups before upgrading. ;) (That's with everything: I've seen Windows upgrades go wrong also)

Answer (score 1):

There are not many major changes in 13.10. You can find a review of it here.

http://www.zdnet.com/ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander-review-smart-scopes-in-mir-out-7000022022/

The biggest change is the addition of more smart scopes, for searching online resources from the dash. I have been finding it useful, however it is not a major change.

It's up to you if you would like to upgrade. Ubuntu 13.04 will be supported into 2014, so there isn't an urgent need to upgrade. See here for the support periods of Ubuntu releases.

[How long will Ubuntu 13.04 be supported for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239278/how-long-will-ubuntu-13-04-be-supported-for)

Naturally however, 13.10 contains some improvements and upgrades to software packages so for that reason, you may want to upgrade.

Comment: I will update soon.

Answer (score 1):

From the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SaucySalamander/ReleaseNotes#Known_issues):

> As is to be expected, at this stage of the release process, there are some significant known bugs that users may run into with this release of Ubuntu 13.10.

This is nothing really too exciting as it will be the same for all new releases. Severe bugs will be fixed very soon, less severe bugs will be fixed over time, some bug will even persist over several releases.

- So if you are concerned about your system stability you should wait for a month after a release to reduce the risk to run into issues.
- In case you feel like being able to fix things you may update on the release day but then it is an even better idea to have a recent backup before upgrading in case you need to revert.